# What steps should I take for describing the architecture before starting Web project?

Tags: php, architecture, symfony1

I am working on the project that is based on symfony (doctrine) with use of a facebook api. I really want to get the description of architecture of in terms of some diagrams, so What steps(in terms of types of diagrams) should I take first before coding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML has some special diagrams useful for describing architecture, such as the [Package diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram) and [Component digrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram). In your case you could describe the Facebook API and your dependencies on it with the component diagram.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the objective behind that diagram. is it for database architecture or code or interface ?

For instance, you can use [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) to design Behavior and structure of your app, or you can use simple page storyboard to present interactions and screens chaining.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things to include in your architecture description in my opinion is the rationale behind your decisions. Why did you choose to separate that component from the rest for example? Or why do you use the facebook api.

You should also look at your audience. Who will read the architecture description? Developers, business analyst, management? UML is great standard to communicate with developers but it does not work as good with business people.